# displaying processing or waiting page in Struts1.3.8 using JSP, When AJAX request made?

Tags: ajax, jsp, struts, pleasewait

In my application there is a drop down box, second drop down box value depends on first.I developed it using AJAX and Struts1.3.8.
When the second drop down box item selects it will display some information of the selected item of select options. Here the processing of the request takes much time. But end user thinks it is not working.So to avoid that i want to display the temporary page displaying
"Processing request.. Please wait...."
How to implement it using AJAX and Struts1.3.8.
In struts2 it is predefined and using stop and wait we can achieve it..
But how to do in Struts1.3.8???
Any idea and response highly appreciatable.

Thanks in advance,
Laxman chowdary

Comment: create the div with your message and hide it initially. When your second box is selected, by using the onchange() show the previously created div. After the processing is completed hide that div..

Comment: Hi Eswar, The result of the second box will be displayed to the end user using div tag only. So how can use the same div for displaying some wait message also. can you explain it???

Comment: when do you want to display message? whether after selecting first box or second box

Comment: After selecting second box, the request takes time to process and give the result back. In the mean time I want to display the message..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in ur ajax code ..use this

```
document.getElementById(disid).innerHTML= "Processing request.. Please wait....";
```

keep rest of ur ajax code the same way ..

Answer (score 0):

This is usefull for your Requirement.Try it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function callLoadingDiv(){
            $("#spinner").fadeIn("fast");
        }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#spinner {
    position: fixed;left: 0px;top: 0px;width: 100%;height: 100%;z-index: 9999;background: url(images/loading.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat #ede9df;
}
</style>
```